# SVG анимация без CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation, linear-gradient

Я хочу создать такую анимацию, которая вращается вокруг двух фигур. И я хочу добиться этого в SVG без внешнего CSS. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне, как это сделать?

Это мой код:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="542" height="542" viewBox="0 0 542 542">
  <g id="svg" transform="translate(-655 -265)">
    <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" cx="271" cy="271" r="271" transform="translate(655 265)" fill="none"/>
    <path id="Path_1" data-name="Path 1" d="M818.25,412.875l.71.931c116.417,110.219-.023,204.664-.382,205.428-.045.089-.2.312-.375.672-2.758,5.713,3.239,3.015,3.594,2.858,147.217-64.969,210.869-212.39,210.672-213.249-.359-1.7-3.069-1.088-3.344-.781-4.366,4.893-81.574,88.727-207.317.617-.169-.118.317.2-.673-.473s-2.369-1.12-3.148-.181-.909,2.256.388,4.35" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path id="Path_2" data-name="Path 2" d="M927.651,569.319s69.788,5.194,99.3,51.994c.017.04,4.351,6.826,5.406-.172a1.6,1.6,0,0,0,.069-.516,5.747,5.747,0,0,0-.21-2.031c-3.036-7.836-31.037-76.552-54.932-98.845-.009-.009-35.627,38.007-49.635,49.57" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
    <g id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" transform="translate(655 496)" fill="#f90a2a" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1">
      <circle cx="34.5" cy="34.5" r="34.5" stroke="none"/>
      <circle cx="34.5" cy="34.5" r="34" fill="none"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Svg animation without css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69777465/7394871) от участника  [@Ghayas Ud Din](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14383601/ghayas-ud-din).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69777465/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если загрузить ваш файл в векторный редактор, то увидим, что фигуры находятся вне холста SVG

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за этого, вы были вынуждены применять несколько команд трансформации `transform="translate(x,y)"` для возврата фигур в зону видимости

*Практический совет:*

Необходимо стараться при создании фигур в векторном редакторе рисовать таким образом, чтобы эти фигуры не выходили за границы холста SVG с учётом ширины обводки. Всё, что выходит за границы холста SVG, будет обрезано (скрыто).

После перерисовки в векторном редакторе и очистки файла svg от лишних команд необходимо:

- Получить сегмент, используя `stroke-dasharray = "251,1004"`, где
  `251` - тире, `1004` - пробел
- Для анимации вращения нужно было помимо угла дополнительно указать
  координаты центра вращения.

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate"
 from="0,266,278" to="360,266,278" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg5" width="50%"  height="50%" viewBox="0 0 542 542" >
 <defs>
   <linearGradient id="Lg" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#DC143C" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.05" />
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>   
<g id="g820" transform="translate(-658 -238)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1">    
   
    <path id="Path_1" fill="black" stroke="black" d="m818 413 1 1c116 110 0 204 0 205l-1 1c-3 6 3 3 4 3a446 446 0 0 0 210-213c0-2-3-2-3-1-4 5-81 88-207 0h-4v4" data-name="Path 1" />
    <path id="Path_2" fill="#DC143C" d="M928 569s69 6 99 52c0 0 4 7 5 0a6 6 0 0 0 0-2c-3-8-31-77-55-99 0 0-35 38-49 49" data-name="Path 2" />
</g> 
   <circle id="Ellipse_3" data-name="Ellipse 3" stroke="url(#Lg)" cx="266" cy="278" r="220" fill="none" stroke="#DC143C" stroke-width="45" stroke-dasharray="251,1004" stroke-linecap="round" >
       <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0,266,278" to="360,266,278" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>  
   </circle>   
   
</svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69779275/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>

Comment: Надо отобрать у вас stroke-dasharray))) Тогда SVG наполовину будет нефункциональным, похоже)))

Comment: @Leonid Спасибо, не согласен, насчет функциональности :))

Comment: Ну в данном случае нет, конечно. Вот изучаю animateTransform (видимо в стиле SMIL). Вы на выходных уже в лес не ездите? Дома сидите?

Comment: @Leonid да, дома, уже живот начал расти в тепле и без движения. ((((

Comment: Живот - плохо, конечно. Зато теперь сколько интересностей попрет здесь от вашего лица...)) Будем ждать, будем посмотреть, и даже будем поучаствовать))

Comment: @Leonid кстати, готовлю вопрос в стиле поршневого механизма для тебя, хочешь?

Comment: Заранее не скажу)) Поглядим - увидим. Интересно когда вызов есть какой-то, а у вас уже и решение готово сразу обычно. Хотя однодневным участникам что-то решать совсем уже надоело. У них даже фантазии не хватает обычно запомнить пароль от входа и ответ посмотреть)) А других вопросов обычно и нет. Вот и получается, что мы тут как Шарик с фоторужьем бегаем за зайцами, чтобы им фотографии отдать. А они им и не нужны. Важно было только вопрос задать...

Comment: @Leonid согласен, кинут плохо подготовленный вопрос и неделю не заходят за ответом, который ждет их. Не понимаю, неужели даже на любопытство не хватает сил (((( Оч. напоминает, когда пацан идёт по улице и у всех подряд просит закурить, а вдруг, кто-то и даст. И тут похоже так, разбросает свой вопрос по всем площадкам и не помнит куда, что бросал ((((

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131002/discussion-between-leonid-and-alexandr-tt).